# SVN - collecting multiple projects into a single baseline version

Tags: svn, version, wrapper, hierarchy

I'm really new to subversion and the concepts of version control, and while I can handle checking in a handful of files into a project, I need some advice on how to scale this up for my needs.

Essentially we are developing an environment, which contains lots of scripts and configurations, which are distributed over many virtual and physical machines. Build scripts, config files, binaries, RPM mirrors etc... and whilst each in their own world they are OK we need some way to aggregate them into a single version. Whilst in a larger coding project I see that this would presumably just be handle with folders in a single SVN project (as I understand it, so probably not...) these thigns really have nothing in common, and many aren't even code, and would just be within SVN as a place holder I imagine. As such, It makes no sense to "check out" the assembled mass of data, but somehow need to relate a top level version number to maybe 60 different pieces of work. As above, this is code, config files, rpm's etc.

I'm initially assuming that we would use SVN for this somehow, but maybe that's a wrong assumption in the first instance. However, from my general purpose view of the requirements I can imagine having the actual projects in SVN and then wrapper projects which are updated on a cronjob (or other trigger) to reference the most recent SVN versions of each project listed within a metadata file within the wrapper project. If any project in the list has changed, then that wrapper project is updated with a new metadata file being checked into it. In turn these wrappers are wrapped by other wrappers up until a single master project. The end use of this master project version is to establish a baseline of projects under it, which woudl be able to be used with documentation and change tracking systems, with a level of automation as well.

Whilst I can envisage what I've just described, it's only based on a very small view of SVN and probably (hopefully) missing a lot of the point of SVN's (or git.... ??) existence.

I hope this makes sense, sorry if it doesn't. More than happy to try to clarify anything.

Thanks

Chris

EDIT: To give an example of the sorts of individual things we need to cover:

- The specific version of the CentOS rpm repositories, as defined by the time it was synchronized from the web
- Nagios configuration files to be installed in a vm after the Nagios packages are installed
- The kickstart scripts used to build the virtual servers
- The scripts used to trigger the deployment of the systems
- The iptables rule sets applied to each type of virtual machine

I'm not concerned here about how these things are done in the slightest, more how we present a view of a what version of each of these things is required at deployment time.

[EDIT] OK, This all boils down to me not really understanding svn versioning. As the revision number is repository wide, all projects implicitly are covered... no actual work is required at all to achieve what I wanted. Thanks, and no wonder I didn't make much sense to anyone else..

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [SVN Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)

Comment: I don't *think* it is. It actually looks largely like the inverse of what I need. I don't actually want all the data in these projects in one place ever, it's of no use in a big pile on one machine. It's more a way to be able to quickly reach each 'leaf' (sorry) version from a single root version number.

Comment: When you define the external, you can define which version of that external directory you want.  In this way, you can aggregate many projects into one, and say "This system is comprised of these versions of these sub-projects".  Is that not what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but you can store many different things in different directories in SVN. Then you can use the [sparse directory](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2007/06/sparse-director.html) feature to fetch just parts of the repository.

so, you can store each machine's config separately if you choose, and only checkout that machine's directory on a particular machine.

What you cannot do in SVN is have the same file presented in 2 different places. So you cannot store abc.config in a top level directory, and then have a view of that exact file in 2 different directory trees. You can do this using externals however.

Comment: Again, it's not about collecting remote projects into one location, but having some form of hierarchy which defines a tree of specific snapshots which collectively define a project version in all the unique ways it's delivered. It's about defining what versions of what comprise an installation of a Linux VM, how the middleware, e.g. apache, is configured on it, which VM's run which pieces of code etc. Making each element work is fine in it's own world, but as we need to deliver, to our developers, a reliable an consistent server infrastructure which can be exactly like it was 3 months ago etc

Comment: you wants tags. Once you've created a tree of folders with stuff in them, and committed them to SVN in a main 'trunk', you can branch the entire lot quickly and simply. It is very space-efficient. Then you can deliver to devs a snapshot of everything as it was when you made the branch. Of course, keeping lots of branches up to date is another matter. If you're storing VM images in svn, you might want to look at an alternative approach.